# How to Get Refresh Token When Using Google Cloud Platform without Client Secret Token?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to implement CI/CD for a Chrome extension based on this [document](https://circleci.com/blog/continuously-deploy-a-chrome-extension/). I've add Chrome Web Sore Api and created a Client ID with Chrome app type because I couldn't find Other type that document is selecting.but I didn't get **client secret** after creating ClientID. I just get **ClientID** and **Creation date**.
based on the document I need Client_Secret to get **refresh_token** with this command:

```
curl "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" -d 
"client_id=$CLIENT_ID&client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET&code=$CODE
&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" | jq 
'.refresh_token'
```

But as I said I don't have Client Secret. How Can Solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I should select **Desktop app** in Application type.